# Hash fragment conflicting with server side code

Tags: php, javascript, fragment-identifier

I have a website where the user chooses a series of letter and numbers and it takes them to a new page based on that.

So it may take them to `/cds/C_1_3_A_2`

There is no actual `C_1_3_A_2` page in the `cds` directory, I have a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cds/(.*) /cds/index.html [L]
```

So that if the requested file doesn't exist, it gets rewritten to `index.html`, where a php script gets the last component of the URL (`C_1_3_A_2`) and it loads the relevant content, if the last component of the URL is `/cds` then the PHP script redirects to `/cds/C_1_1_A_1`

However I would like to add AJAX to make it smoother, which means I need to add support for hash fragments as older browser don't support history.pushState.

So if the user goes by themselves to `/cds/#C_1_3_A_2`, it should be the same as `/cds/C_1_3_A_2`

But as the fragment doesn't get sent to the server, the user ends up as  `/cds/C_1_1_A_1#C_1_3_A_2`, and gets the content relevant to `C_1_1_A_1`, not `C_1_3_A_2` as they intended.

As the PHP is server side, it executes before the Javascript could take care of the fragment, and I'd prefer not to have the user redirected by the PHP script and then back by the javascript.

So how can I add support for hash fragments? How do other sites deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the headers for a request to a page with a hash, the hash portion doesn't even get sent to the web server. So neither php or apache is made aware whether a hash is even present. You would probably be best to just load the index page and not redirect if there is no "last component" and then set the default value via javascript into the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move more of it to the front end.  Normally if the links only consist of a hash fragment they won't trigger a new request (but may cause things like jumping to the top of the screen, which can be dealt with if needed).  It sounds as though your issue here may be adding the "/".  The page should already have the "/" if you want it in the link, and the link should consist of only the hash.

The best way to handle this is to bind to the `window.hashchange` event supported by newer browsers.  There will be polyfills available for older browsers.  When the hashchange event is fired you can retrieve the hash location of the new URL and then use that to do an Ajax request to the backend.

Ideally the backend can be modified so you could add a parameter like `?partial=true` in some form or another so it only returns the content which could be added to the page (without any form of surrounding layout).  That should be the only back-end change that would be needed.  Otherwise to get started you could extract the content from the retrieved data using JavaScript and integrate that into the page (but that should only be temporary while working through things as the full content will still be getting transferred).